# Error expecting begin array while get data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with retrofit and firebase, I have firebase realtime database which return this json

```
 {
   "item1": {
       "img_url": ...",
       "price": 3000,
       "title": "padi"
    },
   "item2": {
       "img_url": "...",
       "price": 2000,
       "title": "tomat"
    }
}
```

My model :

```
public class Panen {

   private String title;

   @SerializedName("img_url")
   private String imgUrl;
   private Integer price;

   //getter-setter
}
```

And here is my retrofit service:

```
@GET("/panen.json")
Call<List<Panen>> getPanen();
```

but whenever I call I always get this error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Any suggestions to why this error is happening?

Comment: How does the entire url look like?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
@GET("/panen.json")
Call<List<Panen>> getPanen();
```

to

```
@GET("/panen.json")
Call<Panen> getPanen();
```

Because your json is not an array, is an object.

Comment: How do i change the json to return as an array? is it possible to do that?

Comment: Did you try this? Did it work? And i dont know how you can change returning json, i dont know how your firebase db is.